# Rolling Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a program in SQL Server that aggregates based on rolling dates.

Take this below

```
Acc Dte     Amount
1   1/1/20    100
1   1/3/20    200
1   1/8/20    100
1   1/8/20     75
2   1/1/20     50
2   1/2/20    100
2   1/3/20     75
2   1/3/20    125
3   1/3/20    100
3   1/6/20     75
3   1/8/20     75
3   1/10/20   200
3   1/10/20   150
```

So the goal is I want to find the avg and the count of records and dates for each account PRIOR TO the  record being analyzed. I also need to sum the records based on the date So based on the above it would look like this...

```
Acc  Dte    Num_of_dates Avg_Amount_per_day Current_Amount
1    1/3/20            1              100              200
1    1/8/20            2              150              175
2    1/2/20            1               50              100
2    1/3/20            2               75              200
3    1/6/20            1              100               75
3    1/8/20            2               83.3             75
3    1/10/20           3               83.3            350
```

The goal is to create a z-score comparing accounts numbers for the current day to the accounts average per day. But we also need to hit a minimum of 10 days of historical data for each account.

Right now my code looks like this and is not working

```
select Account, 
       Dte, 
       (select sum(case when Cast(EventTimestamp as DATE) < Dte then 1 else 0 end) Num_of_Date,
       (select (case when Cast(EventTimestamp as DATE) < Dte then sum(Amount) else 0 end) t_amount
from Data
group by Account, Dte
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: No need to combine those subqueries with group by.

Comment: Try to edit your question and put the sample data in proper columns, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Hi @bryan-egan, welcome to SO. As Jarlh said quite well, a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would definitely help

Comment: I am totally lost on the relationship between the sample data and the explanation.  Dates are not included.  The numbers don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions with proper `rows` clause. For once, `distinct` comes handy here:

```
select distinct
    acc,
    dte,
    count(*) over(
        partition by acc
        order by dte
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) num_of_dates,
    avg(1.0 * amount) over(
        partition by acc
        order by dte
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) avg_amount_per_day,
    sum(amount) over(partition by acc, dte) current_amount
from mytable
```

If you do want just one record per date and account, as shown in your sample data, you can nest the query and use `row_number()` - in absence of an obvious column to define the sorting order, I relied on the cumulative count:

```
select acc, dte, num_of_dates, avg_amount_per_day, current_amount
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by acc, dte order by num_of_dates) rn
    from (
        select
            acc,
            dte,
            count(*) over(
                partition by acc 
                order by dte
                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
            ) num_of_dates,
            avg(1.0 * amount) over(
                partition by acc 
                order by dte
                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
            ) avg_amount_per_day,
            sum(amount) over(partition by acc, dte) current_amount
        from mytable
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1 and avg_amount_per_day is not null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=377af6eb23470af7dc1a3ac93ea3202d)**:

```
acc | dte        | num_of_dates | avg_amount_per_day | current_amount
--: | :--------- | -----------: | :----------------- | -------------:
  1 | 2020-01-03 |            1 | 100.000000         |            200
  1 | 2020-01-08 |            2 | 150.000000         |            175
  2 | 2020-01-02 |            1 | 50.000000          |            100
  2 | 2020-01-03 |            2 | 75.000000          |            200
  3 | 2020-01-06 |            1 | 100.000000         |             75
  3 | 2020-01-08 |            2 | 87.500000          |             75
  3 | 2020-01-10 |            3 | 83.333333          |            350
```

Comment: No need for rn > 1.  Use num_of_dates > 0.  Also, aggregate first.  The output from your query breaks up Acc = 1, Dte = 1/8/20 into two rows.

Comment: @dougp: I just updated my answer - and added a fiddle. I think we need both conditions (`row_number()` and `avg_amount_per_day` - or `num_of_dates`).

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data and description suggest:

```
select acc, dte,
       count(*) as num_on_day,
       sum(amount) as sum_on_day,
       avg(sum(amount)) over (partition by acc order by date_num range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as avg_previous
from t cross join
     (values (datediff(day, '1900-01-01', dte))) v(date_num)
group by acc, dte;
```

I'm not sure why you don't include the first date for each `acc`.